# number xor K - K = number + K xor K, why?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

It seems that with normal integers (bitwise operations) given an integer n and its mask k (with one byte: 1111 1111 for negative numbers and 0000 0000 for positive ones)

```
(n ^ K) - K = (n + K) ^ K
```

and this is often used to calculate the absolute value of the number n with K as its mask. My question is: why does the above expression work? Why are those two terms equivalent?

Comment: And what about abnormal integers?

Comment: Doesn't seem true for n=K=1...

Comment: Doesn't work either with a lot of values.

Comment: Specifically, this never works when `n = K`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that k is the number's mask

Comment: What is "the number's mask" then? -1?

Comment: @JohnnyPauling Do you mean `K = ~n`?

Comment: k (with one byte) is : 1111 1111 for negative numbers and 0000 0000 for positive ones

Comment: For k=0: (n^0)-0=(n+0)^0, ok. For k=-1, ~n+1=~(n-1), try adding n-1 on both sides and notice that n+~n==-1 and n^-1==~n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only seem interested in 2 values of k: 0 and -1.

For k=0: `(n^0)-0=(n+0)^0`, ok.

For k=-1, since `n^-1==~n`, this rewrites as `~n+1=~(n-1)`, try adding n-1 on both sides and notice that n+~n==-1.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's not true. For

```
(n ^ k) - k = (n + k) ^ k =>
((n ^ k) - k) ^ k) = (n + k) ^ k ^k =>
(n ^ k) ^ k - k ^ k = n + k => ### WRONG
n ^ k - 0 = n + k =>
n ^ k = n + k =>
n & k = 0
```

That's the precondition of the equation.

**EDIT**

I made a mistake that xor is not distributive with subtraction. `(a - b) ^ c = a ^ c - b ^ c` is WRONG!

Answer (score 0):

There is an integer overflow with `k = ~0` and `n + k`. So it leads to an undefined behavior.